# Can I resolve a spice netlist to determine what parts I need?

Tags: ltspice, spice

I have used hierarchical schematics in my design, so I can't really "see" anymore what's going on behind the scenes. I want to figure out how many of which parts I need...

I figured that perhaps the easiest way to do this was by looking at the netlist. However, the netlist includes subcircuit definitions, so if I do a search in a text editor for the model name, it doesn't come up with the right number.

Is there a way to resolve a netlist to get rid of the subcircuits? For example, if this is my netlist:

```
V1 N001 0 12
XX1 N001 N002 CIRC1
XX2 N002 0 CIRC2
.SUBCKT CIRC1 A B
R1 A P001 10k
R2 P001 P002 100k
R3 P002 B 10k
.ENDS CIRC1
.SUBCKT CIRC2 A B
R1 A P001 10k
R2 P001 P002 50k
R3 P002 B 10k
.ENDS CIRC2
.END
```

Can I resolve that into:

```
V1 N001 0 12
R1 N001 P001 10k
R2 P001 P002 100k
R3 P002 N002 10k
R4 N002 P003 10k
R5 P003 P004 50k
R6 P004 0 10k
.END
```

Or am I daft, and there is an even easier way to do this?!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Treat it as a [hierarchical BOM](https://www.fuseplm.com/bill-of-materials-software-2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged this with [ltspice](/questions/tagged/ltspice), if you check the menu for `View > Bill of Materials` you'll see two options there. That will not list sources, though generating it on the schematic will make it to automatically update. If you want to do it manually, you can check the `Generate Expanded Listing` option in the `Control Panel > Operation`, and check the error log after the simulation, where you'll see the whole netlist, flattened. It goes without saying that if you have encrypted models, they will not be expanded.

Comment: I absolutely should have included LTSpice in the description. Strangely, the Bill of Materials list is empty?? But Generate Expanded Listing worked as expected and the error log contains exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case 'I guess' you have two sub-circuits and each is used once.

So as far as components are concerned you have:

4 off 10k resistor
1 off 50k resistor
1 off 100k resistor

But, note that internal nets of a sub-circuit instance are unique so create there own top level nets.  If for example you had to instances of 'CIR1' this would add 2 extra 10k resistors and a 100k. It would also add two extra nodes to the netlist.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a way to do this **in general**, not just for this specific example.